# Error in APEX SQL

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I am working on Oracle 11g. I have created a table `STUDENTS` using APEX in my port: 8080 . After that when I use SQLPLUS in cmd and write `SELECT * FROM STUDENTS` it shows `TABLE OR VIEW DOES NOT EXIST`. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Ok...When you created the table using APEX, what schema was it created in?  When you connect via SQL*Plus, are you logging in as the same user who owns the table?

If not, you'll need to `grant select` on the table to the user that wants to access the table, and also either specify the owner when referencing the table in your `select` statement, or create a synonym, or use `alter session set current_schema` statement.